# Retrieve and store elements (according to conditions) from an array

Tags: c, arrays, copy, element, sudoku

Given an array of 81 elements (meant to represent a 9x9 grid) how can I go over each element, grabbing the three around it and then performing an operation on those, then continuing to the next three of each row, column, or submatrix. Look below or at a sudoku grid to see the layout.

```
define COL(n)      ((n) % 9)
define ROW(n)      ((n) / 9)
define SUB(n)      ((n / 3) % 9)
```

For example, I have

```
int grid[81];
```

and

```
int array_x[9], array_y[9], array_s[9];
```

Since the total 9x9 grid can be split into 9 of the following categories, there are nine elements in each array, and I hope to take the elements of each column (the x axis) in groups of threes, perform

```
r = ((a = ~a) & (b = ~b)) | ((b | a) & ~c);

// or

r = ((~a & ~b)) | ((~b | ~a) & ~c);
```

on them, take the three resultant numbers, and perform it on them, and then store it into the array.

If this sounds impossible, sorry, I'd like a different way to do this. Definitely open to suggestions...

Comment: What is the restriction that requires a 81 element vector, instead of a 9x9 array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another try:

```
void applyThingy(int *grid, int xPitch, int yPitch)
{
    int row, column;
    int *rowPointer = grid;

    for(row = 0; row < 3; ++row)
    {
        int *columnPointer = rowPointer;

        for(column = 0; column < 3; ++column)
        {
            doOperation(columnPointer);
            columnPointer += xPitch;
        }

        rowPointer += yPitch * 9;
    }
}

applyThingy(&grid[SUB(n)], 1, 1); // Perform on 3x3 subgrid
applyThingy(&grid[ROW(n)], 1, 0); // Perform on row
applyThingy(&grid[COL(n)], 0, 1); // Perform on column
```

Comment: Ah, not exactly. If I am working on column 0, index 0, I would grab (also) the next two down in that column (which happen to have the indexes 9 and then 18) and perform said operation on them. Repeat this for the next three, etc, and cont. for each column and submatrix.

Comment: @Sid, So you want to perform one common operation for each column, row, and 3x3 sudoku grid?

Comment: @Sid, Are you limited to pure C or can C++ be used?

Comment: Pure C is prefered, but if I can benefit from C++, I'd like to be shown.

Comment: @Sid, Then look at my updated answer.  Or is this not what you want?

Comment: WOOT, SOLVED. Any type of rep I can give you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but is it something like this?:

```
#define IDX(row, col) ((row)*9+(col))

int m = some_column;
for (int n = 0; n < 9; n += 3) {
  a = grid[IDX(n, m)];
  b = grid[IDX(n+1, m)];
  c = grid[IDX(n+2, m)];
  r = ...;
  ...
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what you want to do with your operation

```
r = ((a = ~a) & (b = ~b)) | ((b | a) & ~c);
```

You're assigning `~a` to `a`, is that what you want? How is `a` defined, and what are you trying to set it to? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's simply to avoid having to perform another not operation later. Not sure if it helps. I'm close to giving up on this problem and trying a different solution.

Comment: Although yours might be what I need.

Comment: Gah, hate to post so many comments, but would you have a way to perform that operation on rows and my 'submatrixes'?

Comment: I see... But I think the speedup of this optimization is neglectable, ~(...) is a very fast operation. Also: are you sure the operands are evaluated from left to right? I don't think this is guaranteed. Better stick to the second version, there is still time for improvements once everything works.

Comment: You could just calculate the row numbers in the "main" matrix? If for example your submatrix starts at row 3, it's rows would be at 3+0, 3+1 and 3+2 in the main matrix. Then just access the main matrix at those rows. (The same for columns: If the submatrix starts at 6, the cols are 6+0, 6+1 and 6+2)